# Unable to create foreign key in PHPmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to create foreign key in one of my table but i am getting this error can you help with this

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `albums` (
  `id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `url` mediumtext NOT NULL,
  `year` mediumint(9) NOT NULL,
  `album_name` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `album_cover` text NOT NULL,
  `tracks_id` text NOT NULL,
  `category` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `reciter` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `keywords` varchar(300) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Foreign Key Table Structure

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `album_likes` (
  `album_id` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `likes` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `dislikes` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Now what i did to make this foreign key is that i went to the structure of this table in phpmyadmin and then add constraint name select the columns
Here is the query

```
ALTER TABLE `album_likes` ADD  CONSTRAINT `album_like_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`album_id`) REFERENCES `mp3script`.`albums`(`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
```

The output i got

## 1215 - Cannot add foreign key constraint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A foreign key requires an index on the column you are referencing, in this case `albums.id`.

Add the index:

```
CREATE INDEX ids_nn_1 on albums(id);
```

And you create foreign key should work